# React Fullcallendar v5 event positioning toward cursor issue [UPDATED]

Tags: html, css, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm trying to create a react app with Fullcalendar within it.

I've managed to make it work but i have a strange issue when I'm dragging events within it.[An event element jumps somewhere and then follows my cursor at distance.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joNma.png)

When I'm releasing mouse button event element jumps to highlighted day on calendar. I've tried to add relative positioning to different parent elements to make event positioning inside of them, but no success.

Here is my code

```
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import interactionPlugin, { Draggable } from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import Alert from "sweetalert2";

const Dashboard = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
        let draggableEl = document.getElementById("external-events");
        new Draggable(draggableEl, {
            itemSelector: ".fc-event",
            eventData: function(eventEl) {
                let title = eventEl.getAttribute("title");
                let id = eventEl.getAttribute("data");
                return {
                    title: title,
                    id: id
                };
            }
        });
    }, []);

    const state = {
        calendarEvents: [
            {
                title: "Birthday Party",
                start: new Date("2020-11-17 00:00"),
                id: "99999998"
            },
            {
                title: "Repeating Event",
                start: new Date("2020-11-05 00:00"),
                id: "99999999"
            },
            {
                title: "Repeating Event",
                start: new Date("2020-11-12 00:00"),
                id: "99999999"
            },
            {
                title: "Repeating Event",
                start: new Date("2020-11-22 00:00"),
                id: "99999999"
            },
        ]
    };


    const eventClick = (eventClick) => {
        Alert.fire({
            title: eventClick.event.title,
            html:
                `<div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
      <tbody>
      <tr >
      <td>Title</td>
      <td><strong>` +
                eventClick.event.title +
                `</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr >
      <td>Start Time</td>
      <td><strong>
      ` +
                eventClick.event.start +
                `
      </strong></td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>`,

            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#d33",
            cancelButtonColor: "#3085d6",
            confirmButtonText: "Remove Event",
            cancelButtonText: "Close"
        }).then(result => {
            if (result.value) {
                eventClick.event.remove(); // It will remove event from the calendar
                Alert.fire("Deleted!", "Your Event has been deleted.", "success");
            }
        });
    };

return (
                                    <FullCalendar
                                        headerToolbar={{
                                            left: 'prev,next today',
                                            center: 'title',
                                            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                                        }}
                                        rerenderDelay={10}
                                        eventDurationEditable={false}
                                        editable={true}
                                        droppable={true}
                                        plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
                                        events={state.calendarEvents}
                                        drop={drop}
                                        eventClick={eventClick}
                                        selectable={false}
                                    />
)
};
export default Dashboard;
```

What's I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE:
I've found what happening but I still don't know what to do with that.

I have a left sidebar and header in my project and without those elements FullCalendar is working correctly. Moreover, it also works fine at timeGridDay view and timeGridWeek.

So basically it works incorrectly just on dayGridMonth view. It seems that within dayGridMonth view it doesn't calculates positions correctly.

What can be done here?

Comment: The code doesn't show any obvious problems. Maybe a CSS issue? Do you have any other CSS in the page apart from the fullCalendar CSS?

Comment: @ADyson, sorry for late response, but I've just got to this bug again.

Of course I have other CSS at the page. But I'm not sure how to debug it as the issue is not happening  at timeGridDay view and timeGridWeek

Comment: Thank you for your suggest @ADyson! It was a third-party css causing the issue

Comment: No problem. Btw you don't need to change the title to solved. The fact there is an accepted answer already shows that :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved. Problem was in animated.css I was using. After removing it everything works just fine.

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us what the 3rd party component was in case anyone is searching for something similar?